# How to hide the file url for more security

Tags: php

After I finished a small script that make only members download files from the page I discovered that people can have the file link if they viewed the page source code and download it from there.

So basically the code restrict not members from downloading the file, it even hide the file URL from the address bar, but when someone right click on the page and view the page source code it can have the file real URL, and somehow they can download it without any restriction!

Like this example:

```
https://www.example.com/files/J730F/GalaxyJ72017SM-J730FCOVER.pdf
```

This is my code:

```
if (!(isset($_GET['username']) && !empty($_GET['username']))){
echo 'Only a member of this website can download this file. However, no username was specified in this download. Sorry for inconvenience.'; 
die;
}

$dl_username = $this->decrypt($_GET['username']);

if (gator::getUser($dl_username) == false){
echo 'Only a member of this website can download this file. However, the username provided does not exist in the database. Sorry for inconvenience.';   
die;
}
```

**Is there anyway to hide this thing? like for example use 
.htaccess file to restrict this kind of download!**

Comment: Didn't I say to use the Session for this before.....

Comment: Yes I asked that befure but my qustion was not clear enough, thanks for your time, but I found really simple way to do that, you can see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should store your user information in `$_SESSION` instead of using `$_GET`. Visitors can very easily manipulate `$_GET` so its not reliable at all. You should have a properly login (i.e. with username and password) that stores your user info in `$_SESSION`.

Now, assume you have a `$_SESSION` array with a `"username"` set for login user. You may change the URL you shared from a direct PDF link to a proxy PHP script call, like:

```
https://www.example.com/files.php?path=J730F/GalaxyJ72017SM-J730FCOVER.pdf
```

Then all you need to do is write a proper login check in `files.php` before actually showing the file:

```php
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
  exit('Only a member of this website can download this file. However, no username was specified in this download. Sorry for inconvenience.');
} elseif (!isset($_GET['path']) || empty($_GET['path'])) {
  exit('You must specify the path for download.');
} elseif (strpos($_GET['path'], '../') !== false) {
  exit('Your path contains invalid pattern.');
}

// Note: ideally, $filedir should not be a publicly accessible folder.
$filedir = realpath(__DIR__ . '/files');
$filepath = realpath($filedir. ltrim($_GET['path'], '/'));

// realpath check for security
if (strpos($filepath . '/', $filedir) !== 0) {
  exit('The path you specified is not accessible.');
}

if (!is_file($filepath)) {
  exit('The file you specified does not exists.');
}

// show file, finally
header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($filepath));
echo file_get_content($filepath);
```

Comment: "Note: ideally," .. not really ideally, it has to be for anly level of security

Comment: Be careful with `$_GET['path']` because of Directory Transversal, even though you check `strpos($_GET['path'], '../'`  This does not guarantee prevention, see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74538/alternative-ways-to-exploit-this-path-traversal - The only real way to be 100% secure is to store the filepaths in the DB and give them a lookup key (like the filename), that way they never touch the path.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix: Add some extra precaution to check if the file is within the expected folder.

Answer (score 0):

I just found very simple way to do that
I used this code to block direct access to specific files types
Just add this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(pdf|zip|txt|pcb|bin|rar|7z|rom)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Comment: and what if I'd spoof the `HTTP_REFERER`? relying on this value to be accurate is questionable; therefore considering this a "security measure" is outright absurd. serving files from outside of the web-root, while providing temporary download URL to logged in users, this might yield a decent level of access control.

Answer (score 0):

The good way is to create the .htaccess file in root and add the following script in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```